# Javascript related to search form in navbar doesn't show up in source code

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, navbar, laravel-blade

I added a search form to my partial nav like this:

```
{!! Form::open(array('id' => 'main_search_form', 'url' => 'main_txt_search', 'class' => 'form-inline pull-xs-right', 'method' => 'get')) !!}
        {!! Form::text('main_search',$value = null, array('placeholder' => 'Search', 'id' => 'main_search_input', 'class' => "form-control")) !!}
        {!! Form::submit('Search', array('class' => 'btn btn-info-outline' )) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

which shows up like this in the bar:

[image]

what I want to do is use it with some javascript to use jquery autocomplete and post results of the search in the page without updating it.
The point is where do I put the link to the scripts for the form? I tried to put it in the partial directly but they don't get loaded. My app html is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Project</title>

    <!-- CSS contains bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
    <!-- bootstrap mobile first -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    @yield('scripts')


</head>
<body>


<div class="container">

    @include('partials.nav')

    @yield('content')


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

so what I am thinking here is since the page loads scripts before including the nav it fails to load the script... but since the nav appears in all pages.. where the heck do you put this link to the script?

Comment: As long as it's inside a section in your template, you should be able to put it anywhere in your view.  Perhaps it would help if you showed us the part in your template where you tried to add the script and also verified where you had it was actually inside `@section ... @endsection` tags and that section exists as a `@yield` statement in your master layout.

Comment: I created a nav_scripts.blade.php in partials and put @include('partials.nav_scripts') in head inside app html.

Answer (score 0):

> the page loads scripts before including the nav it fails to load the script

One thing is to have the script *loaded*, that is, fetched from its `src` and loaded into the document, and another is it referencing an html element which itself hasn't been parsed yet.

For the latter, you have to make sure the scripts come after the affected html. Either load them at the end (moving `@yield('scripts')` to the bottom (before `</body>`) or wrap your script with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //
});
```

in order to execute it only after the document is loaded.